# Using ajax calendar extension to update server side chart range

Tags: c#, asp.net

This may be a long shot, but I'm trying to use the client side ajax calendar to select a range of dates for the x-axis of my server side chart. I have both controls set up, I'm just not sure how to get them to communicate with each other or if it's even possible.

This is what I have so far:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
      Start Date
     </td>
     <td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="StartDateTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="StartCal" runat="server" 
          TargetControlID="StartDateTextBox">
     </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>


     </td>
     <td>
     End Date
     </td>
     <td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="EndDateTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="EndCal" runat="server"   TargetControlID="EndDateTextBox">
      </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="4">
        <asp:Chart ID="TrendChart" runat="server" Width="800px" Height="400px">
           <Series>
              <asp:Series Name="Trend" ChartType="Line">
              </asp:Series>
           </Series>

           <ChartAreas>
              <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="true">
              </asp:ChartArea>
           </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">
            <asp:Button ID="TrendChartButton" runat="server" Text="Export To CSV" 
                CommandArgument="TrendChart" onclick="OverviewChartButton_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</table
```